# Simple reporting framework for asp.net with xml, xsl and css

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting

I am searching for a simple framework/library in C#/for asp.net to generate "simple reports" in asp.net.

My requirements are:

- My data are delivered in xml
- I want to use css and xsl
- the reports should be as reusable as possible

Any ideas or experiences?

Thanks in advance
& best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my project that create a WYSIWYP (what you see is what you print) using xml (generated by backend code) and xsl report style plus an viewer (by xsl and css and js and html5) online report.

https://github.com/SiamandMaroufi/webreport